# [behave][selenium][python] Connection error after running one feature in Pycharm

Tags: testing, pycharm, bdd, python-behave

I'm trying to run a test project with 2 features so far. I've tried the following ways:

```
behave "./tests/features/one.feature" "./tests/features/two.feature"
```

```
behave "./tests/features/*.feature"
```

```
behave "./tests/features"
```

but each time I'm getting the same result: one feature (whichever is the first) gets executed perfectly fine but the second results in:

*Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 61] Connection refused*

I've configured closing the browser in after_feature in the environment file. I've tried both close and quit, but the result is the same.

I've also tried setting up an .ini file, but this solution didn't work as well. Running those features separately (one feature in a run) works also fine so clearly running multiple features is an issue.

Does anyone have an idea what might be the issue?

Comment: Without knowing the specifics of your steps/enviroment.py, I'd try temporarily adding a couple of seconds delay i.e. `time.sleep(2)` before and after the  browser close line.

Answer (score 0):

There is not much information of what you have in these feature files/scenarios actually. I assume a browser is not closed correctly somehow between these features.
A good practice would be to open and close a browser for every scenario, regardless a feature file if you have a couple of such web tests in a feature file.
What I usually do is - tag scenarios with `@web` tag and initialize a browser in `before_tag` hook like:

```
def before_tag(context, tag):
    if tag == "web":
        context.browser = webdriver.Chrome()
```

and close it after in the `after_tag` hook like:

```
def after_tag(context, tag):
    if tag == "web":
        context.browser.close()
        context.browser.quit()
```